# Estimator input function random noise processing

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset

Using custom estimators in Tensorflow 1.9.
My estimator training input_function follows the typical pattern but I want to be sure that I'm doing what I think I'm doing. I have this function that I want to apply to every dataset example.

```
def add_noise(data, label):
    tile = data['tile']
    sigma_noise = tf.pow(10.0, -SNR/20.0)
    noise = tf.random_normal(shape=tf.shape(tile), mean=0.0, stddev=sigma_noise, dtype=tf.float32) 
    tile += noise
    return {'tile' : tile}, label
```

So using the dataset API :

```
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=70001)
dataset = dataset.map(parse_function)
dataset = dataset.map(add_noise)
dataset = dataset.batch(32)
dataset = dataset.repeat()
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
```

Is my function add_noise applied on the whole dataset every epoch so that every output example has a new random noise applied to it indefinitely during training process ?

Thank you all :)

Answer (score 0):

from the TensorFlow `tf.data.Dataset` [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map) of the `map` method:

> ```
> map(
>     map_func,
>     num_parallel_calls=None
> )
> ```
>
> Maps `map_func` across the elements of this dataset.
>
> This transformation applies `map_func` to each element of this dataset,
>   and returns a new dataset containing the transformed elements, in the
>   same order as they appeared in the input.

So the dataset from `dataset.map(add_noise)` applies the random noise only once and hence, the iterator returned from `dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()` has only applied the random noise once. If after each epoch you repeat the code where you shuffle your data and apply random noise, etc., then a new random noise will be applied for each epoch, which is what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The dataset.repeat() is supposed to allow infinite epochs buy I wonder if it repeats the dataset operations (which would have noise generated each epoch) or if it just loops the first generated dataset..

Comment: Okay, I have read more of the documentation and from what I saw, I think that the `map` method keeps the function and make a new call to the function at every time the data is called, but I am not sure. A quick way to test if the function is called each time (so that it is generating new noise for your data) is to print a random number at the `add_noise` function and run your program with some dummy data.

Something like `print(np.random.rand(1))`